# running openwrt in virtualbox with 2 network adapters- a host only adapter and bridged adapter, but only host-only adapter shows

Tags: networking, router, virtualbox, openwrt

following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwPD1GWw5go) video to try and set up a virtual network for me to practice hacking, but only the host-only adapter shows (I am currently 17 minutes into the video).

- [uci show network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK2kU.png)
- [ip addr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPFo7.png)
- [/etc/config/network contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H86QD.png)
- [network adapter 1 settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTH5d.png)
- [network adapter 2 settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rTcb.png)

Never tried anything like this before so if you need any more info than provided please just ask and will try and provide, but please be patient :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of your exact use case, but are you doing this with the VM powered on or off. You might try turning the VM off then change the host adapter and see if it works. What options are showing up, and if possible can you show a screenshot of the setting in Virtualbox, or do you mean that it's not showing on the VM after being set?

EDIT:
Verify that you can ping the default gateway from the router.

Ok after seeing your explanation and looking at the picture again. I know when I set up my pfsense router it has a default IP address set for one of the ports on the router and the firewall was blocking traffic. I was used to setting up a new device and not having any configuration already set on it so that threw me off. I would verify that there is not any configuration already set on the device and at the very least add a rule to the firewall to allow traffic until you can complete set up. I see you have 192.168.99.1 address in there, is that something you have set on your network, if not I think that may be the default your router took, and you would need to go to that webpage to configure it. You should verify your default gateway (probably your home router ip address) and that you put in allow rule in the firewall until you have time to set it up completely. As far as the adapter not showing up in devices I think the br-lan is the other adapter but am unsure. I would try getting to the webpage and verifying settings as it's a bit easier to see what is set on everything.

Comment: added images, by not showing up i meant that in the output of ip addr it didn't say UP, LOWER_UP, which i assume means it isn't turned on, and in the /etc/config/network the interface doesn't show up- or it doesn't work, because, whilst i should have internet access, i cannot access the internet ( via ping www.google.com or ping 8.8.8.8)

Comment: the eth1 didn't say UP, LOWER UP